# Same file get download having multiple file

Tags: download

I am trying to download files one by one using angular js. When I click first file. It downloads. If click next file it downloads the same first file. Both the files are placed in the same

I had approached some people but of not use as they are downloading only 1 file

```
<a id="tbFileExport" style="display: none"  href="{{repairEstimate.filePath}}/repairEstimate.fileName}}"    download="{{repairEstimate.fileName}}"></a>
<div ng-if="repairEstimate.estimateRepairNo!=''" style="padding-top: 9px;">                                      <a data-ng-click="downloadFile()"                                          style="color: green">{{repairEstimate.fileName}}</a>

In angularjs

 $scope.downloadFile = function() {
            $("#tbFileExport").bind('click', function() {
            });
            $('#tbFileExport').simulateClick('click');
        }

        $.fn.simulateClick = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                if ('createEvent' in document) {
                    var doc = this.ownerDocument, evt = doc
                            .createEvent('MouseEvents');
                    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true,
                            doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
                            false, false, false, 0, null);
                    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                } else {`enter code here`
                    this.click();
                }
            });
```